# Condição "if e else" para envio Ajax, pegando o texto das tags <span>?

Tags: php, ajax, array

Meio difícil de explicar pelo título, mas é o seguinte, tenho um foreach que imprime dentro uma lista `<ul>` `<li>` tags, e dentro dele tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php if ($row['Status'] == 'Em Processo'):?>                                   
   <span class="process badge" style="background-color:#67A6DF">Em Processo</span>                                  
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($row['Status'] == 'Teste'): ?>
   <span class="test badge" style="background-color:#FCB529">Em Teste</span>
<?php endif;?>
<?php if ($row['Status'] == 'Aprovada'):?>
   <span class="approve badge" style="background-color:#43A995">Aprovada</span>                                                         
<?php endif;?>
```

A ideia é se ele tem um status definido ele imprime qual é, mas eu tenho o seguinte botão:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="flex-icon approved" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprovar" data="5"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Este muda a definição do status, neste caso clicando nele ele mudará o status para Aprovada, então dentro da lista ele munda o `<span>` junto com a lista.

Mas é a questão é, o que não foi testado ainda, não pode ser aprovado, mas não consigo pegar apenas a class process do primeiro `<span>` e enviar em Ajax para não alterar.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.approved').on('click', function(){
        var process = $('.process').text();
            if(process != "Em Processo"){
                var hrefdata = $(this).attr("data");
                 var taskid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id'); 
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: './task.php', 
                        type: 'POST', 
                        data: { id: taskid, approved: hrefdata},
                        success: function(data) { 
                            window.location.reload();
                        }               
                    });//Ajax
            }else{
                alert('Está em processo não pode ser aprovado antes de enviar para teste');
            };//If
    });//Onclick
});
```

Como eu faço para ele pegar apenas ler `<span>` com a classe process e não colocar a mesma condição para as outras?

Bem com a resposta do @KirmayrTomaz consegui resolver meu problema, mas tive que fazer algumas alterações no código.

Se eu utilizar:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.approved').on('click', function(){
        var father = $(this).parent().parent();
        var taskid = $(father).attr('id');          
        var process = document.querySelectorAll("#" + taskid + " .process");    
            if($(process).text() != "Em Processo"){                 
                var hrefdata = $(this).attr("data");
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: './task.php', 
                        type: 'POST', 
                        data: { id: taskid, approved: hrefdata},
                        success: function(data) { 
                            window.location.reload();
                        }               
                    });//Ajax
            }else{
                alert('Está em processo não pode ser aprovado antes de enviar para teste');
            };//If
    });//Onclick
});
```

Tive que fazer a seguinte alteração do ID:

```
<li class="list-group-item id-task" id="<?php echo $row['TasksId'];?>"> ...

</li>
```

Para:

```
<li class="list-group-item id-task" id="task<?php echo $row['TasksId'];?>"> ...

</li>
```

Se apresenta o seguinte erro:

**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#1 .process' is not a valid selector."**

Para retirar a palavra "task" do ID tive que colocar o seguinte código

```
$idtaskapproved = strip_tags($_POST['id']);    
$substrid = substr ($idtaskapproved, 4);
```

Que tira as 4 primeiras strings do POST que estou recebendo.

Olha ficou uma feio mas funcionou.

Se alguém tive alguma ideia para melhorar essa coisa feia.

Comment: cada linha do <span> deve ter uma identificação única para isso.
Recomendo você colocar um ID que não se repete e chamar isso no botão de aprovar. Dessa forma vc estará chamando apenas 1 único 'process'.

Comment: @FabioFila Mas dai problema porque esses <span> iram precisam se repetir, eles estão dentro de um foreach, para cada dado que tenho no banco eles se repetem no html depois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com base no que vc falou para alterar o span. Primeiramente defina um pai que seja tanto para o `approved` quanto pro `process`. No exemplo que fiz coloquei o a div com a classe=taskid daí funciona da seguinte forma

1. Quando o usuário clicar em .approved vc terá que procurar o pai dele `$(this).parent().parent();`
2. Uma vez que vc tem o pai, basta procurar o filho dentro dos ramos. `document.querySelectorAll("#" + taskid + " .process")`
3. Uma vez que vc pegou o filho, dá pra realizar a mudança somente nele.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.approved').on('click', function() {
    //pegando o pai certo
    var father = $(this).parent().parent();
    var taskid = $(father).attr('id');
    
    //pegando o processo certo 
    var process = document.querySelectorAll("#" + taskid + " .process")
      
    if ($(process).text() != "Em Processo") {
     
      var hrefdata = $(this).attr("data");
     //Após sucess da função ajax
          //alterando de processo para approve
          $(process).removeClass("process")
          $(process).addClass("approve").css({
            "background": "#43A995"
          }).text("Aprovada")
 
    } else {
      alert('Está em processo não pode ser aprovado antes de enviar para teste');
    }; //If
  }); //Onclick
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="taskid" id="atividade1">
  <div class="task">
    <span class="process badge" style="background-color:#FCB529F">Em Teste</span> 

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="flex-icon approved" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprovar" data="5"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">Aprovar</i></a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="taskid" id="atividade2">
  <div class="task">
    <span class="process badge" style="background-color:#67A6DF">Em Processo</span> 

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="flex-icon approved" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprovar" data="5"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">Aprovar</i></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Está aparecendo o seguinte erro "Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#1 .process' is not a valid selector."